# Jqzoom not working on safari

Tags: jquery, safari

Hello I am using jqzoom and it is working fine on all browser except safari there is an error 
"TypeError: Result of expression 'smallimagedata.pos' [undefined] is not an object."

Please if somebody can help the page is http://www.legzskin.com/products.php?product=CHARMED when u mouseover the 3 images it should appear zoom window over the flash on the left

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a problem with the smallimagedata properties not being set when the Loader class is used. Here's a workaround that seems to correct the problem.

Update the SmallImage.loadImage() method:

```
this.loadimage = function() {
  this.node.src = image[0].src;
};
```

To this:

```
this.loadimage = function() {
  this.node.src = image[0].src;
  if (typeof smallimagedata.top === "undefined") {
    this.node.onload();
  }
};
```

Comment: This works, for anyone who is interested. I had this issue in Chrome for PC.

Comment: Suggested edit by [Matt Smart](http://stackoverflow.com/users/472900/matt-smart): "This fix does not work on newer versions of chrome. JQZoom appears to be unmaintained at this moment. I found cloud-zoom to be a very viable alternative. It can look exactly the same as JQZoom, and has a couple more features. I'm fairly certain it's based on the same code as jqzoom, but it functions in more browser versions and is very unobtrusive. The only code necessary is the anchor tag class and rel attributes for options, and requires no JS that isn't included in the cloud-zoom source file."

Comment: @Matt I would also post this as a separate answer.